# Немодальные окна

Tags: потоки-данных, окно, messagebox

С++ Builder 
По нажатию на кнопку формы создаётся поток и при каждом нажатии новый поток и выбивает сообщение. Функция потока пишет сообщение произвольного текста MessageBox использую, затем создаю таймер ожидания который отсчитав 5 секунд закрывает это сообщение и выводит его заново. Возникла проблема что это модальный окно и пока не нажмёшь там на кнопку.Таймер не начинает работать. Как сделать немодальным окно? и как потом закрыть программно?

Это что сам навоял

```
 void myTimer() {
         HANDLE hTimer;
         LARGE_INTEGER li;
         const int nTimerUnitsPerSecond = 10000000;
         li.QuadPart = -(5 * nTimerUnitsPerSecond);
         hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
         SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &li, 0, NULL, NULL, FALSE);
         MessageBox(0,L"Моё сообщение",L"Сообщение",MB_OK);//до этой строки не 
         доходит пока не закрою сообщение 
         WaitForSingleObject(hTimer, INFINITE);
         CloseHandle(hTimer);
         }
         DWORD WINAPI EventThread(LPVOID lpParameter)
         {
               m1
               if (MessageBox(0,L"Моё сообщение",L"Сообщение",MB_OK)==IDOK) {

               goto m2;
          }
          myTimer();
         goto m1;
          m2:
         return 0;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется есть 2 способа решить проблему

1. создать своё немодальное окно, похожее на MessageBox (т.е. рисуйте его сами), тогда код будет тем же, что и сейчас за исключением вызова MessageBox (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hf0yazk7.aspx)
2. создать 2 потока, в одном будет вызван MessageBox, во втором будет вызван счётчик, после работы которого будет закрыт первый поток

поток 1:

```
MessageBox
res = WaitForSingleObject(thread2, 0);
if (res == WAIT_TIMEOUT) // второй поток все еще работает
    TerminateThread(thread2, 0); // уничтожить поток 2
```

поток 2:

```
WaitForSingleObject(thread1, 5000);
res = WaitForSingleObject(thread1, 0);
if (res == WAIT_TIMEOUT) // первый поток все еще работает
    TerminateThread(thread1, 0); // уничтожить поток 1
```

т.е. логика такая - первый поток выводит диалоговое окно (модальное) и ждет пока оно закроется, после этого закрывает второй (временной) поток и завершается сам, второй (временной) поток ждет максимум 5000мсек (или пока не закроется первый поток), потом проверяет что первый поток еще работает и убивает его.

Можно написать аккуратнее - через сигналы, чтобы избавиться от TerminateThread

Но общий смысл, надеюсь, нередал

Comment: да спасибо получилось